# connectivity steps of xcode(objective C ) with mysql and code for making student form by retriving data from and to mysql database

Tags: objective-c

I am just a beginner with x code (objective C). I am only known with Mysql. So i want to know simple steps of how to connect with mysql from x code and the code for how to fetch student data from database and how to populate it in the  student form in x code (objectiv C). I have tried a lot from internet but it could not help me.So please tell me a simple procedure which i can understand.
(thanx in advance.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate question. You should have questions that relate to some coding issue. What you are asking for is how to create an app with no knowledge of creating apps. I recommend you pick up a book and read that first. There are tons of great books on iOS and Mac OS programming. I would start with the iOS one from Big Nerd Ranch.